# jPlayer not working properly in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, flash, stream, jplayer

**Problem:**

I have a problem with the jQuery & HTML jPlayer script. Whenever I start my player it works fine, but as soon as I press pause and play again, the musics plays for 2 seconds and it goes on pause after that automatically again... On every other browser it works fine except for Google Chrome.

**Player live stream:** http://www.olympia-classics.nl/player

**Used jPlayer:** https://github.com/jplayer/jPlayer

**Chrome version:** 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

**jQuery version:** 1.12.4

**You can find my code here:** https://pastebin.com/HsniFXDW

**Things I've tried:**

First I thought it had something to do with flash, but after disabling flash in Google Chrome it still didn't work. I also tried removing the `_initCircleControl` function from the script but this did not work as well. I have tested it on multiple devices but on none of them it worked.

**Question:**

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?